# Flutter - I'm trying to scroll a finite list in a loop but am having performance problems

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a challenge right now that involves an infinite scroll of a finite list, repeating it in a loop over and over just like this:

[Image of the loop working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZfon.gif)

I got it to work somehow with a ListView but it will stop working at index 70 (probably cuz of lack of memory).

Has anyone here done this or does anyone have an idea of how I could do it?

Here's my code:

```
class ProfessionalProfileOnboardingImageListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> imageList;
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  final bool isReversedScrolling;

  const ProfessionalProfileOnboardingImageListWidget({
    required this.imageList,
    required this.scrollController,
    this.isReversedScrolling = false,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfessionalProfileOnboardingImageListWidget> createState() =>
      _ProfessionalProfileOnboardingImageListWidgetState();
}

class _ProfessionalProfileOnboardingImageListWidgetState
    extends State<ProfessionalProfileOnboardingImageListWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: widget.scrollController,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        widget.scrollController.animateTo(
          widget.isReversedScrolling
              ? -80 * double.parse(index.toString())
              : 80 * double.parse(index.toString()),
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
        );
        if (widget.isReversedScrolling) {
          widget.imageList.insertAll(0, widget.imageList);
        } else {
          widget.imageList.insert(widget.imageList.length, widget.imageList[index]);
        }
        print(index);

        return Container(
          child: Image.asset(widget.imageList[index]),
          height: 80,
          width: 80,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: Dimens.md),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer to this was using 3 Carousel Sliders with autoplay enabled and some minor tweaks.

If you're facing the same problem please check the lib documentation here: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah. I also managed to do it with carousel slider. maybe add your code here so other people could get inspiration from it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Listview You can use :

```
dependencies:
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.1.0
```

**Example:**

```
class CharacterListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CharacterListViewState createState() => _CharacterListViewState();
}

class _CharacterListViewState extends State<CharacterListView> {
  static const _pageSize = 20;

  final PagingController<int, CharacterSummary> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      final newItems = await RemoteApi.getCharacterList(pageKey, _pageSize);
      final isLastPage = newItems.length < _pageSize;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
      } else {
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + newItems.length;
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _pagingController.error = error;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => 
      PagedListView<int, CharacterSummary>(
        pagingController: _pagingController,
        builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<CharacterSummary>(
          itemBuilder: (context, item, index) => CharacterListItem(
            character: item,
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

For More Kindly Have a [Look](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)

Comment: Thanks Tasnuva, in the end I solved this with Carousel Slider and it worked liked a charm!

Comment: Great to know that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggesting [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider). I managed to do it with some parameter tweaking.

Here is the list of all available options so you can check them out and customise it for your needs: https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/lib/carousel_options.dart

I wanted to achieve a list that auto loops infinitely with the same few items, which can not be interrupted by touches.

### Useful tips

From my experience, setting `autoPlayInterval` and `autoPlayAnimationDuration` to the same Duration, made the animation smooth. Also set the `autoPlayCirve` to `Curves.linear`.

I also found out that `aspectRatio` and `viewportFraction` go hand in hand and you should play around with both if you want to display multiple items in the viewport t t

```
 return CarouselSlider(
      items: [insert items list here],
      options: CarouselOptions(
        aspectRatio: 1.6,
        viewportFraction: 0.5,
        enlargeCenterPage: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: false,
        scrollPhysics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        initialPage: 0,
        autoPlayCurve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    );
```